# How can I notify my PC every time Android changes its IP?

Tags: notifications, vnc

I'd like to send an email or post to a server every time the IP address on the phone changes. This way, I can continue to VNC into the phone, even when the IP changes. Is there an App that would let me send out the IP address, or a bash script I could use?

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work for many hotspots because they do NAT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than a notifier and managing all of this yourself, had you thought about using a [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) client? This would allow you to always use the same name to contact your phone over the internet (or even a local LAN) and the 3rd party would manage the problems with changing IP addresses for you.

There are a number of [Dynamic DNS clients on the Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=dynamic%20dns&so=1&c=apps), I haven't tried any, but it's a pretty common solution for machines that change IP, so I can't see why there'd be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link and tip. I'll check it out a bit more and see if this solution will work.

Comment: This is why we like questions about a problem to be solved, not an "app that does X". There may be solutions that you hadn't considered.